# CSS margins don't work properly with percentages?

Tags: html, css, margin, percentage

I currently have a blog which needs to display profiles (agency style) lists 4 in a line, I've design the website so that when its responsive, and i want these profiles to work responsively. At this time it works, but when using 50% without margins, but id like spaces between them of 10px, when those margins are added with the code below, they don't align, please also see jfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/b0rrz8bg/

CSS

```css
.new-agency-clients{
position: relative; 
border-radius:6px; 
background:#fcfbfc !important; 
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fcfbfc),to(#f7f6f7)) !important; 
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfbfc,#f7f6f7) !important;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top,#fcfbfc 0,#f7f6f7 100%) !important; 
background:-moz-gradient(center top,#fcfbfc 0,#f7f6f7 100%) !important; 
width:940px; 
height: 100%; 
box-shadow:0 0 3px #444; 
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #444; 
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #444; 
padding-top: 10px; 
margin-top:10px; 
margin-bottom:10px; 
}

.new-agency-clients-box {
overflow:hidden;
}

.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile {
bottom:0;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:10px; 
margin-bottom: 10px;
float:left; 
position:relative; 
width: 225px; 
height: 270px; 
background: #ffffff; 
border-radius: 6px; 
overflow:hidden; 
box-shadow:0 0 3px #444; 
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #444; 
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #444; 
}

.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile .profilename { 
margin-top: -35px; 
line-height: 26px; 
height: 28px;
width: 100%; 
background:#cccccc; 
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#eeeeee),to(#cccccc)); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee,#cccccc); 
background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top,#eeeeee 0,#cccccc 100%); 
background:-moz-gradient(center top,#eeeeee 0,#cccccc 100%); 
color: #444; 
display: block; 
font-size: 14px; 
font-weight: bold; 
position: relative; 
border-radius: 0px !important; 
}

.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile .profile-box-image{ 
background: #0e0e0e !important; 
width: 225px; 
height: 270px; 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
cursor: pointer; 
position: relative; 
}

.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile .profile-box-image:hover{ 
filter: alpha(opacity=60,Style=0); 
opacity: 0.6; 
cursor: pointer; 
}

.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile .profile-box-image a img{ 
width: 225px; 
height: 270px; 
position: absolute;
margin: auto; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
}

.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile .profile-box-image a img.default{
width: 225px; 
height: auto; 
position: absolute; 
margin: auto; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

.wrap {width: auto;} 
.new-agency-clients {width: 100%;}
.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile {width: 50%; height: 50%;}

}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="new-agency-clients">
<div class="new-agency-clients-box">

<div class="entry-profile">

<div class="profile-box-image">
<a href="" rel="bookmark">
<img width="700" height="875" src="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />  
</a> 
</div>
<center>
    <div class="profilename">
        <h6><a href="" rel="bookmark" title="">Profile</a></h6>
    </div>
</center>
</div>

<div class="entry-profile">

<div class="profile-box-image">
<a href="" rel="bookmark">
<img width="700" height="875" src="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />  
</a> 
</div>
<center>
    <div class="profilename">
        <h6><a href="" rel="bookmark" title="">Profile</a></h6>
    </div>
</center>
</div>    

<div class="entry-profile">

<div class="profile-box-image">
<a href="" rel="bookmark">
<img width="700" height="875" src="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />  
</a> 
</div>
<center>
    <div class="profilename">
        <h6><a href="" rel="bookmark" title="">Profile</a></h6>
    </div>
</center>
</div>    

<div class="entry-profile">

<div class="profile-box-image">
<a href="" rel="bookmark">
<img width="700" height="875" src="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />  
</a> 
</div>
<center>
    <div class="profilename">
        <h6><a href="" rel="bookmark" title="">Profile</a></h6>
    </div>
</center>
</div>    

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please trim this down to the minimal set of code necessary to reproduce the problem. Which I assume you already did in the process of trying to track it down?

Comment: @torazaburo, he did add the exact minimum code to describe his issue

Comment: @Fabio I'll take your word for it, seemed like a lot of extra cruft in there to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your approach to responsive layouts leaves a lot to discuss, in your specific case just do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

.wrap {width: auto;} 
.new-agency-clients {width: 100%;}
.new-agency-clients-box .entry-profile {width: calc( 50% - 10px ) ; height: auto}

}
```

CSS margins are working correctly, but if you have 50%+10px, then it's obvious the element will take 50%+, thus wrapping to next line. Therefore, we use `calc` to make those elements 50% *MINUS* the margin you want and voilá, it works like magic. I have [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk2j53a6/) so you can play around

**EDIT:** Including new code as per comment

Change this HTML

```
<img width="700" height="875" src="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />
```

to this (we're removing the width and height from markup, which, anyways, you shouldn't use):

```
<img src="" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />
```

Now, in your CSS, it's as easy as this:

```
.entry-profile .wp-post-image{width:100%; height:auto; max-width:700px;}
```

See that we could also use `width:auto; height:100%; max-height:875px` and also restrict the min height or width like this `width:auto; height:100%; max-height:875px; min-height:200px /* or restrict the width if you want */` . All approaches, while relatively similar, have different behaviors on resizing, but all of them are responsive, so test them with your code and see which one you prefer for your project.

Use one and resize and see how the element behaves and you'll understand how easy it is, which is nothing but, for example "the image will take 100% of the containing element, adjusting automatically to a maximum width of 700px and a minimum width of 200px "

All this being said, which is basic theory, see you'll probably prefer in most cases to apply max and min width to the containing element, so your CSS will slightly change and everything will be even easier

```
.entry-profile{width: calc( 25% - 10px ) /* 4 columns! */ ; max-width:700px; min-width:200px}
.entry-profile .wp-post-image{width:100%; height:auto; /* responsive scalable images no matter the size of container */}
```

Comment: Thank you fabio much apprechiated :)

Comment: I was wondering if you might be able help with the code above as i have another problem, percentages are not my thing, but I'm trying to get the image to display full width and height of whatever .entry-profile is, the image is always the same size and doesn't adjust to .entry-profile div

Comment: That's why I said "your approach to responsive layouts leaves a lot to discuss" ;) Luckily for you, it's not difficult, just keep in mind that you need to use relative measures rather than fixed measures (you can use this for min and max measures, just not fixed unless absolutely needed by design). In your case, it's as simple as the edit in the answer (it's easy for me to include the code)